# Gradient of a Mahalanobis distance

Tags: linear-algebra

**Short question:**

How can I calculate $\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial L}$ where $A = \|Lx\|^2_2= x^TL^TLx$?

Is it $\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial L}=2Lx^tx$?

**Long question:**

I want to calculate the gradient of a Mahalanobis distance. 
More specifically, I like to calculate the gradient of $A$ in terms of $L$, ($\frac{\partial A}{\partial L}$).

$$A = \|Lx\|^2_2= x^TL^TLx$$

I expand the equation and calculate the gradient element by element and it seems it should be something like $\frac{\partial A}{\partial L}=2Lx^tx$. But, it's very slow! Would you please confirm the correctness of answer? and help me find a faster approach?

Thanks

Comment: Hint to check your solution: what happens when L is a scalar?

Answer (score 6):

It's inded tedious to do it by hand.

See first that $$\frac{\partial {\bf L x }}{\partial L_{ij}}=  {\bf P^{ij}  x}$$

where ${\bf P^{i,j}}$ is the "singleentry matrix": it is zero everywhere except in the entry $i,j$ where it's 1. (This can be checked, an also deduced from the product rule, knowing that $\frac{\partial {\bf L }}{\partial L_{ij}}=  {\bf P^{ij}}$)

And similarly: $$\frac{\partial {\bf x^t L^t }}{\partial L_{ij}}=  {\bf x^t P^{ji} }$$

Then, applying the product rule:

$$\frac{\partial { \bf x^t L^t L x }}{\partial L_{ij}}= { \bf x^t L^t} {\bf P^{ij}  x} +  {\bf x^t P^{ji} L x } = 2 \; { \bf x^t L^t} {\bf P^{ij}  x} $$

Now the [Matrix Cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) comes to the rescue (*"The single-entry matrix is very useful when working with derivatives of expressions involving matrices"* - page 52), by using formula *431* (page 53) we get the result:

$$ \frac{\partial { \bf x^t L^t L x }}{\partial L_{ij}}=   2 ({\bf L x x^t })_{ij} \Rightarrow  \frac{\partial { \bf x^t L^t L x }}{\partial {\bf L}}= 2 {\bf L x x^t }$$

BTW, this is formula 69 in the same Cookbook.

Edited:  I had messed some indexes, I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(L) = Lx $  and then from the [Wikipedia article on matrix calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus):

$$ \frac{\partial ||Lx||^{2}}{\partial L} = 2\cdot{} ||Lx||\cdot{}\frac{\partial}{\partial L}(||f(L)||)$$
$$ = 2\cdot{}||Lx||\cdot{}\biggl[\frac{\partial}{\partial f}(||f(L)||)\biggr]^{T}\cdot{}\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}$$
$$ = 2\cdot{} ||Lx|| \cdot{} \biggl[\frac{(Lx)^{T}}{||Lx||}\biggr]^{T}\cdot{}x^{T} $$
$$ = 2\cdot{}Lxx^{T}.$$

**Edit** -- I updated to include missing transpositions.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to go back to the definition of the derivative. Let us fix $x$, and let $H$ be any $n \times n$ matrix. Then:

$$A (L+H,x) = ((L+H)x,(L+H)x) = (Lx,Lx) + 2(Lx,Hx)+(Hx,Hx)$$

$$A (L+H,x) = A (L,x) +2(Lx,Hx)+o (\|H\|).$$

Hence, $\frac{\partial A}{\partial L} (L,x)$ is a linear form which maps a matrix $H$ to $2(Lx,Hx)$. Moreover, you can check that for any vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and any $n \times n$ matrix $M$,

$$ (x,My)_{\mathbb{R}^n} = (x y^T,M)_{\mathcal{M}_{n,n} (\mathbb{R})},$$

where the former scalar product is taken over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the later over $\mathcal{M}_{n,n} (\mathbb{R})$. Hence:

$$2(Lx,Hx)_{\mathbb{R}^n} = (2Lx x^T,H)_{\mathcal{M}_{n,n} (\mathbb{R})} = \left( \frac{\partial A}{\partial L},H \right)_{\mathcal{M}_{n,n} (\mathbb{R})}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Define the vector $$v=Lx \implies dv=dL\,x$$
Write the distance in terms of this new variable.
Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 A &= \|v\|^2 = v^Tv \cr
dA &= 2v^Tdv = 2v^TdL\,x= 2\,{\rm Tr}(xv^TdL) \cr
\frac{\partial A}{\partial L} &= 2vx^T = 2Lxx^T \cr
}$$
Or perhaps the transpose of this, depending on your choice of [Layout Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions).